# watching the route and changing a variable in a directive's scope.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a directive below, which creates a set of buttons based on the data that is provided to it.

```
angular.module('btnbar.directive', ['messaging']).
directive("btnBar", function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
      $scope.buttons = [{href: '#/students', icon:'icon-ok'},
                         {href: '#/students', icon:'icon-remove'},
                         {href: '#/students/new', icon:'icon-plus'}];    
    },
    template:'<div class="btn-toolbar">' +
      '<a class="btn" ng-repeat="b in buttons" href={{b.href}}>' +
      '<i class={{b.icon}}></i></a></div>',
    replace:true
  }
});
```

The above directive works well. Every time the ng-view in the view changes, I would like to pass a new array for the buttons.

So I want to do the following 2 things -

1. Watch for the change in the route.
2. On change in the route, change the 'buttons' var in the 'btnbar.directive' scope.

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can inject the $location service watch for it and then update the $scope.buttons accordingly when something happens. This would be my attempt

```
angular.module('btnbar.directive', ['messaging']).
directive("btnBar", ['$location', function($location){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template:'<div class="btn-toolbar">' +
      '<a class="btn" ng-repeat="b in buttons" href={{b.href}}>' +
      '<i class={{b.icon}}></i></a></div>',
    replace:true,
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $scope.buttons = [{href: '#/students', icon:'icon-ok'},
                          {href: '#/students', icon:'icon-remove'},
                          {href: '#/students/new', icon:'icon-plus'}];
        // What for the location
        $scope.$watch(function() {
            // You can define what part of the $location you want to watch for
            // E.g. $location.search().something (if you are only interested in that)
            return $location;
        }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            // Do something with the $scope.buttons;
        });
    }
  }
}]);
```

I hope that helps.